# Why does new Date().toISOString() give different output in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, date

Why does `new Date().toISOString()` give different outputs when given the same date?

```
console.log(new Date("2023-11-26").toISOString())
// "2023-11-26T00:00:00.000Z"

console.log(new Date(2023, 11-1, 26).toISOString())
// "2023-11-25T21:00:00.000Z"
```

Comment: Because the two ways of constructing a date make different assumptions about what you want.

Comment: The difference is how you use the Date object constructor, nothing to do with toISOString()

Comment: Because dates without a timezone don't mean anything. Using a string as constructor argument is equivalent to using [Date.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date#datestring) and does so in the assumption you meant UTC. Using numeric arguments uses "whatever timezone you're in right now, good luck".

Answer (score 1):

When you pass a date string to the `Date` constructor in the date-only form (e.g. `YYYY-MM-DD`), it is interpreted as a UTC time. When passing separate date and time component values as arguments, they are considered relative to the local time zone, not UTC.

Comment: "When the time zone offset is absent, date-only forms are interpreted as a UTC time and date-time forms are interpreted as local time." -- Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#date_time_string_format

Comment: @Unmitigated Will "T21:00:00.000Z" in the second example always remain constant relative to the local time? If hour, minute, second information is not entered.

Comment: @BloggerKlik Not necessarily; for instance, daylight savings can cause changes. It's far better to be specific about the exact time you want rather than relying on this.

Comment: @Unmitigated What I want is to keep today's date and convert it to ISO format. Without Hour, Minute, Second information. I will use operators on the date.

Comment: @BloggerKlik Then, yes, your second method works for that.